# Why can't this retieve the download URL of an image on Firebase Storage?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I am trying to retrieve an image from firebase storage for an android app by getting the download url of the image I want to retrieve in the onSuccessListener of the putImage call I used to upload the image in the first place. I am saving the download URL in a field variable but the issue is that the field variable is not being updated. I used toast to print out the value of the url field variable after my attempt in setting it equal to the download URl of the image I want to retrieve, but it remains unchanged. I'm not sure why this is the case so I would appreciate any help in resolving this.

```
//field variable that s meant to hold download url for the image I want to retrieve
String url = "never changed"
```

...

```
final String imageKey = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        StorageReference profileref = storageReference.child("contactProfiles/" + imageKey);
        profileref.putFile(imageUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                Task<Uri> task = taskSnapshot.getMetadata().getReference().getDownloadUrl();
                task.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                        //setting url equal to url of the image I want to retrieve 
                        url = uri.toString();
                    }
                });
                Toast.makeText(ContactCreation.this, "Successful Profile Picture Upload", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        })
         .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
             @Override
             public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                 Toast.makeText(ContactCreation.this, "Failed to Upload Profile Picture", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }
         });

  //Seeing if the url changed or not
        Toast.makeText(ContactCreation.this, url, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: Please only use the `android-studio` tag for questions about the Android Studio IDE itself. For questions about Android programming in general, use the `android` tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The call to `getDownloadURL` makes a call to the server, and thus is executed asynchronously. This means that right now in your code, the `Toast.makeText(ContactCreation.this, url` runs before the `url = uri.toString()` ever runs, which explains why it logs no value.

The solution is always the same: any code that needs the value, needs to be inside the `onSuccess` that is called with the value, or it needs to be called from there.

So:

```
task.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
        url = uri.toString();
        Toast.makeText(ContactCreation.this, url, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

If you're new to such asynchronous behavior, I recommend reading some more about it. For example with:

- [URL generated by Firebase Storage does not allow access to the file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53652406/url-generated-by-firebase-storage-does-not-allow-access-to-the-file/53653522#53653522), which shows some chaining of `Task` listeners.
- [How to get the download url from Firebase Storage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53299915/how-to-get-the-download-url-from-firebase-storage/53300660#53300660)
- [Hello, I have problem to upload my image to my firebase storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60784959/hello-i-have-problem-to-upload-my-image-to-my-firebase-storage/60785037#60785037)

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realize it was asynchronous haha.  I appreciate  you linking the additional resources as well.